# scrapy for table content in pdf file

Tags: python, pdf, web-scraping

I am working on web scraping for tables in pdf file using python

Can some one suggest me a good module which fetch's only required table
I have tried pypdf,pdf2html,ocr,slate but nothing works

Thanks

Comment: Can you please explain what it is you are trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

First, convert PDF to HTML. See [Converting PDF to HTML with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276434/converting-pdf-to-html-with-python).

And then, using an HTML parsing library, parse the HTML generated from the PDF. See [BeautifulSoup HTML table parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059328/beautifulsoup-html-table-parsing)