# Python & Beautiful Soup - Searching result strings

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am using Beautiful Soup to parse an HTML table.

- Python version 3.2
- Beautiful Soup version 4.1.3

I am running into an issue when trying to use the findAll method to find the columns within my rows.  I get an error that says list object has no attribute findAll. I found this method through another post on stack exchange and this was not an issue there. ([BeautifulSoup HTML table parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059328/beautifulsoup-html-table-parsing))

I realize that findAll is a method of BeautifulSoup, not python lists.  The weird part is the findAll method works when I find the rows within the table list (I only need the 2nd table on the page), but when I attempt to find the columns in the rows list.

Here's my code:

```
from urllib.request import URLopener
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

opener = URLopener() #Open the URL Connection
page = opener.open("http://www.labormarketinfo.edd.ca.gov/majorer/countymajorer.asp?CountyCode=000001") #Open the page
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

table = soup.findAll('table')[1] #Get the 2nd table (index 1)
rows = table.findAll('tr') #findAll works here
cols = rows.findAll('td') #findAll fails here
print(cols)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`findAll()` returns a *result list*, you'd need to loop over those or pick *one* to get to another contained element with it's own `findAll()` method:

```
table = soup.findAll('table')[1]
rows = table.findAll('tr')
for row in rows:
    cols = rows.findAll('td')
    print(cols)
```

or pick *one* row:

```
table = soup.findAll('table')[1]
rows = table.findAll('tr')
cols = rows[0].findAll('td')  # columns of the *first* row.
print(cols)
```

Note that `findAll` is deprecated, you should use `find_all()` instead.